# What is the difference between the different kinds of blocks?

Tags: dragon-ball-fighterz

Playing through Dragon Ball Fighterz, I notice experienced players sometimes crouch and block, stand and block, or jump and block selectively. I've tried the different blocks myself, but I often get knocked out of my block mid-combo and the attacks happen so quickly that I haven't been able to put together a consistent strategy for when to block what kind of attacks.

What is the difference between the different blocks, and is there a good general strategy for how to block combos successfully?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some specifics when it comes to blocking.

You have your usual **standing block** (just holding back), it will block **mid** attacks and **overhead** attacks, but **won't block low** attacks.

And you have the **crouch block** (hold back and down), this will block **mid** attacks and **low** attacks, but you'll be **wide open for overhead** attacks.

You should be able to tell which "height" property an attack has just by looking at the character animations:

- **Mids** come out when the character's in a standing position
- **Lows** usually come out when they're crouching, although there are some exceptions
- **Overheads** may have some sort of wind-up before they strike, aerial attacks will register as overheads as well.

Blocking will not save you from being thrown

The game also has a tutorial mode where it teaches you these and other basic mechanics of the game.